# no module named 'importSDF' error in RobotCreator

Tags: gazebo, sdformat

I want to create a world (a school maybe) to simulate multiple robots navigating in there and trying to create a map for that school (I am using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04).

So, the first simulator that came to my mind was Gazebo because it's popular, but when I followed their tutorials to create a world in `sdf` formats, it was just a tedious process and I think it would take me weeks just to make a simple world.

So, I found some random old reddit post talking about using CAD tools like `freeCAD`  to build the world then export the design using tools like [RobotCreator](https://github.com/maidenone/RobotCreator) to export the design to `SDF` file format.

I followed the instructions on the Repo by downloading the repo then putting the main folder under `/usr/bin/freecad/Mod/` but when I tried to export the body design in freecad to sdf file I keep getting the error `no module named 'importSDF'`, I examined the files of the repo and I think the problem comes from these 2 lines:

```
FreeCAD.addImportType("SDF (*.sdf)","importSDF")
FreeCAD.addExportType("SDF (*.sdf)","importSDF")
```

which are found in the file called `init.py`. so is there any solution to my problem or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the RobotCreator, but I can provide some hints on how to build a world for Gazebo:

- Option 1: install Gazebo Classic and use its [building editor](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=build_world&tut=building_editor).

  Gazebo Classic can be installed side-by-side with Gazebo Sim (i.e. 'New Gazebo') up to Gazebo Sim Fortress. From Garden on, this is no longer possible due to a name clash of the `gz` executable. But you can still compile from source or use a docker image.
- Option 2: draw your model in a 3D modeler (e.g. Blender or Fusion360), export as `.dae` file (Collada) and import in Gazebo.